# Which model should i use to be able to achieve accurate predictions based on a large amount of data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, supervised-learning

I have been trying to build a model that would consider a independent variable such as "age" to predict the level of efficacy of an individual. I have achieved a 0.049 r2 scored by using polynomial regression and decision tree algorithm but it is still really low. What would be the best way to tackle this issue?

Here is the code:

```
#Load data into a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv("workers.csv")

# Split data into training and testing sets
X = df[['sub_age']]
y = df["actual_efficacy_h"]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

#Create polynomial features
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=4)
X_poly = poly.fit_transform(X)
X_train_trans = poly.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_trans = poly.transform(X_test)

# Train a linear regression model on the training data
model = DecisionTreeRegressor()
model.fit(X_train_trans, y_train)

# Make predictions on the test data
y_pred = model.predict(X_test_trans)

# Evaluate the model's performance
mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
r2 = r2_score(y_test, y_pred)
print("Mean squared error: ", mse)
print("R-squared score: ", r2)

X_new = np.linspace(18, 65, 200).reshape(200, 1)
X_new_poly = poly.transform(X_new)
y_new = model.predict(X_new_poly)
plt.plot(X_new, y_new, "r-", linewidth=2, label="Predictions")
plt.plot(X_train, y_train, "b.",label='Training points')
plt.plot(X_test, y_test, "g.",label='Testing points')
plt.xlabel("Age")
plt.ylabel("Degree of Efficacy")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This code achieves the following:
Mean squared error:  0.15122979391134947
R-squared score:  0.04171398183828967

And plots a graph like this:
[Plot Produced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zImzY.png)

I would appreciate any kind of help or guidance.

Thank you

Comment: How sure are you that you can predict the target variable with only one input feature? What is the correlation between age and efficacy?

Comment: The correlation between these variables is around 0.11. The other variables have a similar correlation or lower. Should that mean that it is not possible to produce accurate predictions? And in that case, is it possible to use these variables with low correlation to either analyse how they affect the variable efficacy?
Thanks

Comment: ML modeling can't find a relationship that isn't there. The beauty of it is that you can use multiple low-correlation features to create a more predictive model. Try putting more of your features into `X` to improve your predictions